# mediaplayer error (1, -5001)

Tags: android

What is the problem?
What does -5001 mean?

05-03 15:09:00.766 21171-21183/com.finnq.masil.dev V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-5001
05-03 15:09:00.766 21171-21183/com.finnq.masil.dev E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -5001)

```
public Object instantiateItem(View pager, final int position) {
    View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_guide, null);
    v.setTag("video"+position);

    final VideoView video = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.guide_item_video);
    LinearLayout text1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.guide_item_text1);
    LinearLayout text2 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.guide_item_text2);
    LinearLayout text3 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.guide_item_text3);
    LinearLayout text4 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.guide_item_text4);

    int videoRawData = 0;
    if (position == 0) {
        videoRawData = R.raw.intro_01;
        text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        videoRawData = R.raw.intro_02;
        text2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (position == 2) {
        videoRawData = R.raw.intro_03;
        text3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if (position == 3) {
        videoRawData = R.raw.intro_04;
        text4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    String uriPath = "android.resource://" + mCtx.getPackageName() + "/" + videoRawData;
    video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uriPath));
    video.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (viewpager.getCurrentItem() != position) {
                        video.pause();
                    }
                }
            }, 100);
        }
    });
    video.start();

    ((ViewPager) pager).addView(v, 0);
    return v;
}
```

Comment: What's your code? What library are you using?